# Trying to identify and rename a file with an original name that contains a random number

Tags: vba, excel, filesystems

Hi there I am trying to rename a file in a folder (with multiple similar files), but I have a hard time identifying it even with the wildcard method. The original file name looks like this: "2018_02_26_20180228_XXXXXX_GDW_Audit_CView_Report.txt" so my only way of identifying it is knowing parts of the name ("_GDW_Audit_CView_Report.txt") as the date is the same across multiple files. I wrote the following code which gives Path/File Access error when I try to run it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Sub HGDW_WKD()

    Dim myDateTemp As String
    Dim myDate1 As String
    Dim myDate2 As String
    Dim HGDW_CV1 As String
    Dim HGDW_CV2 As String

    myDateTemp = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    myDate1 = Replace(myDateTemp, "-", "_")
    myDate2 = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")

    HGDW_CV1 = myDate1 & "_" & myDate2 & "*_GDW_Audit_CView_Report.txt*"
    HGDW_CV2 = "35999_HR_Global_Data_Warehouse_CView_PROD_" & myDate2 & ".txt"

    Name "C:\Users\bf91955\SourceFldr\" & HGDW_CV1 As _ 
    "C:\Users\bf91955\SourceFldr\" & HGDW_CV2

End Sub
```

Comment: You say that date is always the same but you have 2 different dates in the name (`2018_02_26` and `200180228`). Is one of these static? also any of these dates todays date? or are they just random dates?

Comment: So is it just one file which has _GDW_Audit_CView_Report.txt in that you are trying to find?

Comment: The dates are today's dates. We receive the reports daily and the filename is generated by the feed like this. Yeah for starters I am trying to identify one file that contains _GDW_Audit_CView_Report.txt and the given day's date.

Comment: you are actually trying to rename a file called C:\Users\bf91955\SourceFldr\2018_02_28_20180228*_GDW_Audit_CView_Report.txt*    is this what you meant? Unless you have * in the name you should get a file not found error or some such?

Comment: the file looks like this: 2018_02_28_20180228_614712_GDW_Audit_CView_Report.txt where 614712 is a random number different every day, so I cannot define an exact filename for the code. I get wrong file number/folder access error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you mean but you can use the Dir function with wildcards to try and get the filename.

So say I had a file called

2018_02_28_20180228_XXXXXX_GDW_Audit_CView_Report.txt

I can retrieve the actual name as follows. First match. No real error handling if not found just test that string is assigned a value other than that which it was initialized with. You can pass the folder path as a variable.

```
Sub TEST()

    Dim fname As String

    fname = Dir("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\*_GDW_Audit_CView_Report.txt")

    If fname <> vbNullString Then

        Debug.Print fname

    End If

End Sub
```

Example passing a folder variable and date1 (note date1  = "2018_02_28" as of this moment) :

```
Sub TEST()

    Dim myDate1 As String

    myDate1 = Format$(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd")

    'Debug.Print myDate1

    Dim fname As String
    Dim folderPath As String

    folderPath = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test"

    fname = Dir(folderPath & Application.PathSeparator & myDate1 & "*_GDW_Audit_CView_Report.txt")

    If fname <> vbNullString Then

        Debug.Print fname

    End If

End Sub
```

And why did I use `Application.PathSeparator` ?  You should really test for the presence of a separator before trying to add one. In this case I used it for compatibility reasons. This will use the correct separator across Mac and Windows.

For info see here:

[Excel 2016 Power Programming with VBA (2016)
Part IV. Developing Excel Applications , Chapter 21. Understanding Compatibility Issues](http://apprize.info/microsoft/excel_2/22.html)

Quote:

> If your code deals with paths and filenames, you need to construct
>   your path with the appropriate path separator (a colon for the Mac, a
>   backslash for Windows). A better approach is to avoid hard-coding the
>   path separator character and use VBA to determine it. The following
>   statement assigns the path separator character to a variable named
>   PathSep:
>
> PathSep = Application.PathSeparator

Reference:

http://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-dir-function.html

Comment: I tried the Dir version, but I couldn't add the date variable as an identifier, as I'd need it too for weekend reports (3 different files received on Monday). Would it work if I do something like this: `fname = Dir("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\ & myDate1 & *_GDW_Audit_CView_Report.txt")`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I'll adapt the Dir/Wildcard method then. Just curious: what is the benefit of using `Application.PathSeparator` instead of just putting `& "/" &` or something? Clarity?

Comment: Is a compatibility thing.